# How to disable babel-loader in webpack using craco config?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, craco, esbuild

I've added esbuild to my CRA project using craco-esbuild. But it seems webpack still continue use default babel-loader to transpile my ts/tsx code. How can I disable it using craco config?